# Parsing Nested Nodes from XML in XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xmldocument

I'm using .net to parse an XML. Below is the XML that needs to be parsed. I need to gather the id  from `Animal` and info from `AnimalName`, `AnimalPicture` and `AnimalPicture` type.

```
<AnimalEntry version="2.0">
  <Animal id="1">
   <Information>
     <Type>
       Indoor Pet
     <Type>
    <AvailableTypes> //always only 1 type
      <AvailableType> 
         <Active> 
             <AnimalName> Rupert</AnimalName>
             <AnimalPictures>   //Always only 1 picture
                 <AnimalPicture type="jpg"> random.jpg <AnimalPicture> 
            </AnimalPictures>
         </Active>
      </AvailableType>
    </AvailableTypes>
    <Price>10000</Price>
   </Information>
  </Animal>
</AnimalEntry>
```

I can gather the id as follows:

```
            XmlDocument xDoc new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(xmlUrl);

            XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0];
            string id = node.Attributes["id"].Value;
```

I'm not familiar on how to tackle the nested nodes. Is there a recommended way to get the nested AnimalName, AnimalPicture and OwnerId? Do I need to call a foreach or is there a way I can directly get the node?

Comment: I prefer/am more familiar with, System.Xml.Linq.XDocument but you [can use xpath to select nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Crowcoder would you recommend installing XDocument?

Comment: I find it easier but it is your preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq to xml.

```
var xml = XElement.Load(xmlUrl);

int id = (int)xml.Element("Animal").Attribute("id");

var active = xml.Element("Animal")
    .Element("Information")
    .Element("AvailableTypes")
    .Element("AvailableType")
    .Element("Active");

var animalName = active.Element("AnimalName").Value;
var animalPictureNode = active.Element("AnimalPictures").Element("AnimalPicture");
var animalPicture = animalPictureNode.Value;
var animalPictureType = animalPictureNode.Attribute("type").Value;

Console.WriteLine(id);
Console.WriteLine(animalName);
Console.WriteLine(animalPicture);
Console.WriteLine(animalPictureType);
```

Open namespace:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq to xml, u can try something like this. If you this approach verbose, you can also try xpath using linq [how-to-query-linq-to-xml-using-xpath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-linq-to-xml-using-xpath)

```
        XElement element = XElement.Parse("Xml data");

        foreach (XElement xe in element.Elements(XName.Get("Animal")))
        {
            string id = xe.Attribute(XName.Get("id")).Value;
            var allChildrens = xe.Descendants();

            string animalName = allChildrens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "AnimalName")?.Value;
            string animalPicture = allChildrens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "AnimalPicture")?.Value;
            string animalPictureType = allChildrens.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "AnimalPicture")?.Attribute(XName.Get("type"))?.Value;
        }
```